# Is it bad practice to add an encrypted private key to source control?

Tags: encryption, opensource

I understand that it is bad practice to add passwords and secret tokens to source control, with obvious implications arising if you are working on an open-source or related project.  Rather, you should store them as environment variables.

However, is it legitimate to add an *encrypted* private PEM key file to source control for an open source project, and only keep the decryption password as an environment variable?  Or should I store the entire contents of the PEM as the environment variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing *insecure* with what you are suggesting.

However, *why* would you want to store a private key in your source control? If I fork your project, why will I be using *your* private key? It is obvious that I would want to generate and use my own private key, so make that part of the setup process.

Comment: Unless I wanted to spoof someone else?

Comment: Travis CI does this so you can encrypt access tokens for private repos and such.

Comment: Also useful if you want to be able to restore the configuration of your laptop with a single command: https://github.com/cristiklein/puppet-developer-laptop

Comment: I am wondering if this does not add risk. If a flaw in the encryption of the private PEM key is discovered, you can bet that an army of bots will decrypt all PEMs on GitHub. Is this scenario worth worrying about?

Comment: // , What if you need to revoke it? Now `git bisect` doesn't work any more.